# PerformanceCounter.NextValue hangs on some machines

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I don't know why, but many computers hangs on following operation:

```
void Init()
{
    net1 = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
    net2 = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
    foreach (string instance in new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface").GetInstanceNames())
    {
        net1.Add(new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", instance));
        net2.Add(new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", instance));
    }
}

//Once in 1 second
void UpdateStats()
{
    Status.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < net1.Count; i++)                    
         Status.Text += string.Format("{0}/{1} Kb/sec;   ", net1[i].NextValue() / 1024, net2[i].NextValue() / 1024);
}
```

On some computes program hangs completely on first call of `UpdateStats()`, others experiencing 100% CPU load but program works (slowly). Other counters like `new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total")` seems to work fine.

Any suggwstions why is that?

Comment: WTB Observer-Pattern based Performance Counters, gogo Rx

Comment: I think this could be a permission issue...

Comment: We have same issue here. It just hangs, maybe similar to this one: http://sharepoint.nailhead.net/2010/05/application-hangs-caused-by-calling.html

So far the solution is to have another thread to detect if the counter thread hangs more than the expected time then just close it and instantiate another thread

Answer (score 1):

Removing printer references helped eliminate a hang on the initial

```
  new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total").
```

Now we get a fresh error message instead of hang so can trace it.  From:

[Answer about printer drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209366)

We had two similar dell laptops (one newer), both with Windows 8, MVSV 2013, and IIS Express 8.   One would hang, one would not.