# Can't get Performance Counter Instance Names using C#

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I am trying to get a list of all performance counter instance names on the local machine for a named Category. When I call the static `GetCategories()` method or construct my own instance of the `PerformanceCounterCategory` class and call `GetInstanceNames()` the process just hangs and they never return.

for example:

`var categories = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()`

or

```
var categoryStruct = new PerformanceCounterCategory("the name");
var instances = categoryStruct.GetInstanceNames();
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here, or maybe there is another method I can use to get this information.

For context, I am running VS 2013 as administrator when performing this test. Also, I can perform all other functions related to counters with no problem (*e.g. read values, set values, etc...*), the issue only comes up in relation to the above calls.

Comment: There's a similar question where a bad printer hung the perf counters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209366 - read the code reference notes in the questions as well as the OP's own answer. As noted by the other question, does the same computer also hang while trying to view the "Devices and Printers"? If so, that may be a culprit.

Answer (score -1):

http://toncigrgin.blogspot.hr/2015/11/windows-perf-counters-blog3.html:
(New-Object Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory($Category)).GetInstanceNames()

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10347857)

Comment: (New-Object Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory($Category)).GetInstanceNames() *is* the answer.

Comment: JoeGeeky asked in the context of c#. While the link does refer to the instrumentation functionality accessed via the Powershell command interface it does not address the hanging issues and if it does its over shadowed by other info in the blog post. I'd like for an answer to address the question directly with a c# code example here on this page.

Comment: Eniac, I am sorry my answer offended you. Powershell is .NET based and runs C# code natively. In this case, it means it is using same classes as you would in C#. The only important thing is that you have (System.Diagnostics.)PerformanceCounter Class and PerformanceCounterCategory Class. Once you know that, it's just a matter of iterating PerformanceCounterCategory Class. Hope this helps. The actual C#  code can be found at [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.getinstancenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).