# Performance Counter NextValue hangs forever

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I'm using Performance counter in my application to collect the remote system performance information. Normally, it works fine without any issues. But in some cases, like if the network connection goes down or remote system itself goes down during Performance collection i.e., during `NextValue()` call, then it is never returning back.

I tried searching but couldn't find anything useful. But please note, this is not happening for all the systems, only for the some of the systems this happens.  Also i tried to see if there is any timeout available for NextValue() call, again i couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code would be useful in helping answer this question.

Comment: Perhaps related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868068/performancecounter-nextvalue-hangs-on-some-machines